# HTML Page is not rendering for a specific URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am using Node js (Express framework) in the backend. A POST ajax call is made from HTML to node js.

```
function myFunction(queue_name)
   {
       $.ajax({
            url: "/getQueueDetails",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'queuename':queue_name},
            success: function(){
                console.log("success!")
            }
        })
   }
```

In the backend, here's the route handler function for the route /getQueueDetails

```
app.post("/getQueueDetails",function(req,res){
    var selected_queue = req.body.queuename;
    var showURL = "/showQueueDetails?queue="+selected_queue ; 
    console.log(showURL)
    res.redirect(showURL)
})

app.get("/showQueueDetails",function(req,res){
    var selected_queue = req.query.queue ;
    console.log(selected_queue)
    res.render("space_tracking_detail.html",{queuename:selected_queue,username:username,serverName:serverName})
})
```

There's no error, but "space_tracking_detail.html" didn't render. 
But if I directly enter the URL - localhost:8088/showQueueDetails?queue=default, it render the "space_tracking_detail.html".
NOTE: Other html pages are getting render in this Index.js file

Comment: Possibly the redirect of the POST to `getQueueDetails` is itself a POST [1] to `showQueueDetails`;  what happens if you add a `app.post()` for `showQueueDetails`?

Comment: @landru27 I have tried that too, didn't work

Comment: The rendered page is returned to the `success` function of the ajax call `success: function(the_rendered_page){ console.log(the_rendered_page)`. It's the ajax call that is redirected, which doesn't mean the browser gets redirected too. Instead of the ajax you could simply do `location.href = '/showQueueDetails?queue=' + queue_name` and it would do what you want since all the post request does is the redirect.

Comment: in the case where `space_tracking_detail.html` does not render, does the `console.log()` line just above the `res.render()` line show anything?  and, if you add a catchall `app.get()` with lots of debug logging, does that show anything that might provide any hints?

Comment: @landru27 Yes console.log() printed the correct value

Comment: @Molda Yes you're right. The rendered page is returned to the success function of ajax. I am now using window.location.href. It is now working. Thanks a lot !